# MySQL Query duplicates sum for left join

Tags: mysql, join, query, sum

I have 2 tables, Greeter_Detail and ZipCode_Details

I'm trying to SUM the total of People and Families from and Greeter_Detail and join them on ZipCodes, but I get duplicates. ZipCode_Details has city and county info. Can anyone help, I've been on this for hours. Seems like it should be straight forward. TIA!

```
    SELECT SUM(Families), SUM(People), Zipcode, ZipCode_Detail.Zipcode_D, ZipCode_Detail.City, ZipCode_Detail.County
    FROM Greeter_Detail
        
    LEFT JOIN ZipCode_Detail ON Greeter_Detail.Zipcode = ZipCode_Detail.Zipcode_D

    WHERE $dateRange
    GROUP BY Zipcode
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "total of People".  Can you provide a _short_ set of data and the desired result?

Comment: Did you try to use `SELECT DISTINCT` OR use `DISTINCT ` in one of the aggregate functions? I feel using the keyword `DISTINCT` is the key for your query and this question altogether. Let me know

Answer (score 0):

```
COUNT(*)  counts rows
COUNT(DISTINCT name)  counts how many different `name` there are
SUM(cost > 1000)  counts how many are expensive
```

Beware of what happens with `NULL` values; some counts include them; some don't.

If you need to gather two different counts from different tables, you may need subqueries for each count.

```
SELECT
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) ... ) AS foo_count
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) ... ) AS bar_count
```